# JSP: Test if a variable from pageContext.findAttribute("") exists

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I set this `context.setAttribute("isGood", isGood)` in a servlet to be able to get the value on a JSP file with `pageContext.findAttribute("isGood")`.

Sometimes `context.setAttribute("isGood", isGood)` could not be set so it doesn't exist and my JSP gives me an error because it can't get it.

How can I test if `pageContext.findAttribute("isGood")` exists in my JSP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional check tag as:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.getAttribute("isGood") != null }">

</c:if>
```